# Skip a line in Firebase data structure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It's hard for me to explain this. But, how do I skip a line in the Firebase data structure in order to write a value deeper in the tree like so: `https://myownproj.firebaseio.com/messages/i_dont_know_the_name/user`

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- messages
           |
           ---- -Kjf489hj4983h3bhj
                   |
                   ---- meessage: "Hello!"
                   |
                   ---- user: john
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messagesRef = rootRef.child("messages");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String meessage = ds.child("meessage").getvalue(String.class);
            String user = ds.child("user").getvalue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
messagesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't want read `https://myownproj.firebaseio.com/messages/i_dont_know_the_name/user` I want to *write*

Comment: You did not mention this in your question. The code above is for reading data. Because setValue() method works directly on the reference, if you don't have a particular id, you cannot use it that method. Unfortunately if you don't have that id, you cannot go down the tree.

Comment: Okay, that's all I need to know.